# Mysql join or php in_array() which is better to optimize Mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a watch-list functionality to my current project,in which users can add items to their watchlist.
So up to adding the items to watch list works fine but when displaying all items(that in watchlist and not in watchlist collectively) in a particular category,I need to check whether the item in the users watchlist or not and if it is not in watchlist i have to show a button to add to watch list.....if it is already in watch list a button to remove it.
So here I had following tables

**watch-list** table

item-id(int)
username
date-added (to watch list)

**items** table 
item-id(int)
item-name
item-description
date-added
**users** table
username
fname
lname
joinDate

At present when a user visits items page there are number of mysql queries
1 query for user check(if logged in get username at the top of the page)
1 query for showing articles(using category filters)
**Many queries** to show whether an item is in watch list.
 
I am using a query inside a loop which checks for **username** and **item-id** pair from **watchlist** table and grab the item-id compares that with present article and desides whether it is in watch list  (I know it is a bad way ...but I used that for a start  as I am a beginner)
If there are 20 items displaying per page there will be 20 queries if 30 items 30 querys and so on....So I just started to figure out ways to optimize it.

**One** way that I was thinking to implement is to grab the all the **item-id** in the **watch-list** table  with one query to an array and check using php **in_array()** before printing the items to the page and print appropriately

**I think this works fine for now.But as I am  a beginner I want to learn best practices to optimize queries**
Is this good to go or can some of you suggest other techniques.
Some of you may suggest to use joins .......but I don't know how to use them in this scenario.If it is a better way ....can some one explain me how to use joins in this scenario

Thanks in advance
Shrikanth

Comment: As a rule of thumb, queries are expensive : they imply a return trip to the database server, with possibly the need to open/close a connection, and in many cases also writing out the query to a log file, which adds yet more I/O to the mix. The _less_ queries you can do with, the better. If you can replace *n* queries with a single one, do it. O(1) is hands down better than O(n).

Comment: Getting a list of watched items for a user in one query instead of a loop is an obvious optimization that can be easily done, one simple inner join with items to filter category should be enough. You might even left join watchlist table to your rowset for the query showing articles, but you have to test it as using a different query for every user may have bad impact on query cache and we don't see how do you actually do that category filtering.

Comment: @Piotrm thanks for your suggestions.  And to do category filtering,there are (3)more columns in the items table which are intended for categorizing items.But I haven't shown them in the question.Yes the query will be different for each user....if so can you suggest any other possible alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts are right, and it would be better to use a join, as this might save you the additional queries for each item.

What you have to do now: Use a `left join` to determine if the entry is watchlisted. (if it is  NOT, the right handed result of the join will be null.

It would look like this (untested):

Selects all Watchlisted items for current user.

```
SELECT 
 i.* 
FROM
 items i
LEFT JOIN
 watch-list wl
ON
  i.item-id = wl.item-id AND
  wl.user-id = {$currentUserId}
WHERE
  NOT isnull(wl.item-id) --if theres a right side, its watchlisted
```

Vice Versa, selects all NOT watchlisted

```
SELECT 
 i.* 
FROM
 items i
LEFT JOIN
 watch-list wl
ON
  i.item-id = wl.item-id AND
  wl.user-id = {$currentUserId}
WHERE
  isnull(wl.item-id)
```

Selects ALL items and inserts a flag to determine wheter the item is watchlisted or not.

```
SELECT 
 i.*,
 IFNULL(wl.item-id, "0") as watchlisted -- will be > 0 if watchlisted.  
FROM
 items i
LEFT JOIN
 watch-list wl
ON
  i.item-id = wl.item-id AND
  wl.user-id = {$currentUserId}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion. You helped me figure out what to do.I will try to implement this

Comment: But I also have to count the total number of items in the watch list.So earlier,with one query i just added all the items in watchlist to an array, counted no of entries in that array to display total no of items in watchlist(for navigation eg:**Watchlist(3)**) and then one more query to retrieve all items according to the filters and check with php in_array() function to display whether it is in watch list or not.With **Left Join** I think I need one more query to count total no of items in the watchlist.Both methods result me 2 queries. Any other suggestion to get total no of items?

Comment: @Shrikanth: After fetching all watchlistitems, just use `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: I think you didn't get my problem.I need to do 2 things .One showing the total no of items in the watchlist(Through out the site) for Navigation purpose.Second to show Items satisfying to category filter(s).And while displaying the articles belonging to a category,i need to check whether each item is in watchlist or not and display accordingly ( **Add to Watchlist/InWatchlist-Remove**).And yes with **Left Join** I can do the second part perfectly.But counting all items from  watchlist I need one more query **SELECT COUNT('item-id')  FROM watchlist WHERE user='$current_user'** .2 queries again.